# -[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdictionary

I am getting the error of

-[NSDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of keys (2)'

here is my code in saving the plist.

```
    @interface setting : UIViewController{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet UILabel * morningtime;
    UIDatePicker *afternoonpicker;
    NSString*morningtime1;
    NSString*afternoontime1;
     IBOutlet UILabel *afternoontime;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *afternoonpicker;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *morningtime1;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *afternoontime1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *morningtime;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *afternoontime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *morning;




- (IBAction)savetext:(id)sender {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    self.morningtime1 = morningtime.text;
    self.afternoontime1 = afternoontime.text;
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: morningtime1, afternoontime1, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Morning", @"Afternoon", nil]];

    NSString *error = nil;
    // create NSData from dictionary
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // check is plistData exists
    if(plistData)
    {
        // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are the `NSString` properties marked as `IBOutlet`? There's no reason for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`morningtime1` is almost certainly `nil` here, prematurely ending the array list.

If you used the new array literal syntax here:

```
@[morningtime1, afternoontime1];
```

you would get a crash, because it's illegal to assign nil to an `NSArray` element.

Comment: why not `afternoontime1`  nil?

Comment: Because the count of objects is zero.  (afternoontime1 could be nil as well, but you never get that far.)

Comment: Well, `afternoontime1` might also be nil, but if the array count is 0, that implies that the first item in the list is terminating the list.

Comment: You guys aren't addressing the reason why the ivars are nil.

Comment: There are at least three different reasons the ivar might be nil, but identifying that it *is* nil, and that passing a nil variable into a varargs list causes unexpected results, seems like the most salient point here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. However, I still have no idea how to fix this problem. Where should i start from? I also notice one thing, i tried to enter value in the plist file, only afternoon label give value while the morning label has nothing on the label? Does it means the problem comes from the morningtime1??

Comment: Answer these questions and you should have a solution: a) is `morningtime1` the ivar for `self.morningtime1` (do you have a line that says `@synthesize morningtime1=morningtime1`?) b) is the `UILabel` `morningtime` non-nil in `savetext` (did you actually connect the outlet; is the view loaded when you call this method, etc), and c) is there actually text in `morningtime`?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: morningtime1, afternoontime1, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Morning", @"Afternoon", nil]];
```

should be:

```
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.morningtime1, self.afternoontime1, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Morning", @"Afternoon", nil]];
```

In other words, reference the properties, not the ivars. As you have it, the `morningtime1` ivar is never set (you set the property which is actually setting the generated ivar named `_morningtime1`).

Side note:

Get rid of any explicit ivars and `@synthesize` lines for the properties. This will avoid such confusion.

Comment: @downvoter - why? The `morningtime1` ivar is nil because it's never set. By changing the code to use the property, the problem goes away.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter and I agree that these are good practices, but there's no assurance here that using the ivar reference is the issue.