# Indeterministic behaviour when using unarchiveObjectWithData in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm having problems with the below code in Swift. I extracted the code from one of my apps and setup a Playground to test its behaviour.

Sometimes the below line succeeds, and sometimes it fails:

```
if var selectedCards = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? [Account : Card] {
```

Nothing is changed between runs in the Playground.

If anyone could help me out it would be very much appreciated. It's driving me crazy!

When the line fails in the Playground it fails with the below error:

> Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>   (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0

When the line fails in my app it fails with the same error and this is printed in the debug console:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**Playground**

```
import Foundation
```

**Account class**

```
class Account: NSObject, Comparable, NSCoding, NSCopying {

    var email: String = ""
    var locked: Bool = false

    override var hashValue: Int {
        return email.hash
    }

    required init(email: String) {
        super.init()
        self.email = email
        self.locked = false
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        email = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("email") as! String
        locked = decoder.decodeBoolForKey("locked")
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(email, forKey: "email")
        coder.encodeBool(locked, forKey: "locked")
    }

    func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject {
        let account = self.dynamicType.init(email: self.email)
        account.email = self.email
        account.locked = self.locked
        return account
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let account = object as? Account else { return false }
        return account == self
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Account, rhs: Account) -> Bool {
    let emailEqual = lhs.email == rhs.email
    return emailEqual
}

func <(lhs: Account, rhs: Account) -> Bool {
    return lhs.email < rhs.email
}
```

**Card class**

```
class Card: NSObject, Comparable, NSCoding {

    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""

    override var hashValue: Int {
        return id.hash
    }

    init(id: String, name: String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        id = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("id") as! String
        name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(id, forKey: "id")
        coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        guard let card = object as? Card else { return false }
        return card == self
    }
}

func ==(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
    let idEqual = lhs.id == rhs.id
    let nameEqual = lhs.name == rhs.name
    return idEqual && nameEqual
}

func <(lhs: Card, rhs: Card) -> Bool {
    if lhs.name == rhs.name {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id
    }
    return lhs.name < rhs.name
}
```

**Test**

```
let account = Account(email: "user@domain.com")
let card = Card(id: "1", name: "Card 1")

let map: [Account : Card] = [account : card]

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(map)

if var selectedCards = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? [Account : Card] {
    let selectedCard = Card(id: "2", name: "Card 2")
    selectedCards[account] = selectedCard

    print("Success")
}
```

Comment: `... as? [Account: Card]`: have a look at your required failable initializers for these two classes, e.g. the forced type conversion `email = ... as! String` and `id = ... as! String`.  These will not fail and return `nil` in case the decoder (e.g. for key `"id"`) yields `nil` prior to the forced casting (`as`), rather, they will crash. Try re-writing these initializers using safe unwrapping of the object decoding (e.g. optional binding), returning `nil` if the decoding fails (hence failing initialization rather than crashing it).

Comment: Suspect I might just need to add @objc(Account) before the Account class, and @objc(Card) before the Card class, so non-mangled class names are used

Comment: Thanks dfri. Definitely worth doing. However, it should be working and this doesn't explain why it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't when the data is the same

Comment: The `NSKeyedArchiver` is not relevant here, as we can boil down the same issue to just explicitly attempting to create an `NSDictionary` as `[account: card]`, i.e. `let map: NSDictionary = [account : card]` (or just `[account: "foo"]`). This also fails sporadically with fatal error _"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"_. Naturally `NSDictionary` can't hold keys that are `nil`, but I can't explain why `account` would indeterministically yield `nil` when entered as key/value into the `NSDictionary`. [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909714/) seems related.